# Laravel Voyager: Repeating "App/Public" in image url on admin side

Tags: laravel, voyager

When I add a restaurant/upload an image using voyager. The image displays correctly on user side but doesn't show on admin side. when i inspect the url of the image it shows "app/public" is repeating twice.
If I update the restaurant info and let the image be the same. then it even stops working on the user side too. After inspecting the URL i got to know that the "app/public" keeps repeating the number of time i update the restaurant.

Images directory

```
public_html/tmo_api/storage/restaurants/July2021
```

**I've already tried symlinking again. and cache clear etc...
**

Voyager.php

```
/*'storage' => [
    'disk' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),
],*/
'storage' => [
    'disk' => 'voyager',
],
```

filesystems.php

```
 'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/app/public',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],
    'voyager' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),// change here something specific to your application need
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/app/public',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

],
```

app.php

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://example.com/tmo_api'),

'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:sdfswm8pJN6QQls+sdfRfsd56NQw8XBsdsdfdSW/saVPQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://example.com/tmo_api
```

[You can see it repeating on ID-6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml7MR.png)

Comment: please share your code not image

Comment: @A.ANoman please check...

Comment: @A.ANoman will you respond now?

Comment: First of all you have to save your image as timestamp

Then in admin panel you have to add full URL path like `http:\\xyz.com\tmo_api\storage\restaurants\July2021\{{your_image_name}}

Comment: @A.ANoman even pasting code didn't help you understand... i think my question is clear enough... uploading image is done by voyager admin ui... it works fine but the image (in voyager admin ui) doesn't work. after inspection i got to know "app/public" was repeating... but it was working fine everywhere (user side)... but when i update restaurant (using voyager admin ui) the image stops working on user side too... when i check in database the image path has "app/public" repeating the n of time the post is updated...

Comment: When you update restaurant,  do you update  related image too?

Comment: @A.ANoman if i update the image too... it works... the image shows on user side but not on voyager admin side (app/public) repeating twice in image url.... if i dont update the image and update some other info of restaurant, the image doesn't show, neither on user nor on voyager admin side... the number of time i update the image, "app/public" repeats in the url of the image...